# jQuery.off() is not removing binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason jQuery.off('click') doesn't seem to be working here. When the 'Yes' button is clicked in the model another model just pops up. What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
$(function(){

  //If there are warnings on the page bind alert
  if ($('.renewal-warning').length > 0){

    (function (){

      $('#signRentalContainer').on('click', '.renewal-warning', function(e){

        var buttonHandle = this;

        //Prevent submission
        e.preventDefault();

        //Show warning model
        $.modal({
          content: $('#renewalWarning').html(),
          title: "Order Renewal Warning",
          buttons: {
            'Yes': function(win) { $(buttonHandle).off('click').click(); },
            'No': function(win) { win.closeModal(); }
          },
          maxWidth: 250,
          closeButton: false
        });
      });
    })();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty sure you're going to need to provide it the same element, as well as the same selector.

```
$('#signRentalContainer').off('click', '.renewal-warning');
```

In the `.on()` handler, `this` is the `'.renewal-warning'` element that was clicked, not the `#signRentalContainer` element.

---

If there are several of these `'.renewal-warning'` elements, and you only want to disable one at a time, the simplest way is to change its class so that it no longer matches the selector.

```
$(this).removeClass('renewal-warning')
       .addClass('renewal-warning-disabled');
```

Comment: Why isn't the handle working in this case though? I thought jQuery changed scope to match the event?

Comment: @Steven: Oh, is that why you're doing the `.off()`? I'm guessing the event is bubbling. Instead of `off()`, try adding `e.stopPropagation()` to the handler.

Comment: ...or maybe it's because of the `.click()` that you're doing on the element that was already clicked. Why is that there? Try removing it.

Comment: I need the link to go through in the end though which is why the second .click() is there.
Basically if the user clicks the link and clicks 'yes' in the popup I want the browser to be sent to where ever the link was destined. I would just grab the href from the link, however there is a case where a second event may be bound to that element and I still want that to be triggered.

Comment: @Steven: Then instead of `click()`, you should do `window.location.href = this.href`.

Comment: If I bound a second click event after binding the "renewal-warning" event would that still get processed?

 For example, if I wanted to send an ajax request when that link is clicked but only if the link actually "went through", and I bound that ajax request to the "click" of the element after the warning, would the ajax request be made?

Comment: @Steven: By "went through", do you mean that the `this.href` was successfully followed? I suppose you may be able to fire off a request before you follow the `href`, but you'd never get the response. I'd also guess (though I'm not certain) that the request would be cancelled once you leave the page. But then if it's an AJAX request, perhaps you should wait for the response before redirecting to the `href`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6730/discussion-between-steven-and-am-not-i-am)

Answer (score 3):

Because the `this` refer to the context of the handle function, not the function itself.

Try making it a named function, then refer to it when you call `off`:

`$("body").off("click", '#signRentalContainer', buttonHandle);`

BTW, any reason we can't use `unbind` directly here?

`$("#signRentalContainer").unbind("click");`

Comment: reason for not using unbind: Just trying to stick with the what the jQuery team recommends.

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements." [Source](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: @Steven "preferred".. that's a word I don't want to hear on documentation. It's either the way to do or not the way to do.. "preferred" sounds crazy